# PHP PDO Update statement returns true but not updating DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two update statement in my query, But only one works. I tried to comment out the first one that works to try the second one. When i `dd` it returns true but the table is not updated. Can someone tell me what should I do? Thanks

Here are the queries

```php
$q = "UPDATE data_file SET 
file_name=?,file_size=?
WHERE module_id = ". $this->module_id;
   
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 
$updateStmt = $this->conn->prepare($q);
$updateStmt->execute([
    $this->file_name,
    $this->file_size,
]);
  
//this query returns true but not updating the database
$q1 = "UPDATE server_status SET file_start = ? AND gps_start = ? WHERE module_id = ". $this->module_id;
$updateStmnt2 = $this->conn->prepare($q1);
$stat = $updateStmnt2->execute([
    1,
    $date
]);
//query 2 end

Responses::http_ok();
```

Comment: Did you try checking if the module_id in your WHERE exists in your server_status table?

Comment: yes. there is one record there and its not updated even i put static values in pdo

Comment: module_id is primary using varchar(255) @crimson589

Comment: Try changing `SET file_start = ? AND gps_start = ?` to `SET file_start = ? , gps_start = ?`

Comment: `$this->module_id` should also be passed in as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for db updating is `update [dbtable] set field1=xxxx, field2=xxxx where [condition(s)]`

Hence, please change in your update query from

```
SET file_start = ? AND gps_start = ?
```

to

```
SET file_start = ? , gps_start = ?
```